# $interval not running, angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm not sure why this code isn't running.  I'm trying to set up a simple counter that increases every second using angulars $interval wrapper.

```
angular.module('app').controller('testController', function($scope, $interval){
  var set_counter = function(){
    var start_time = new Date(2014, 09, 02, 0,0,0,0).getTime()
    var time_counter = new Date().getTime()
    $scope.counter = Math.ceil(time_counter / 1000000 + ((time_counter / 1000 - start_time / 1000) * 0.5)).toLocaleString();
    console.log($scope.counter);
  }
  $interval(set_counter(), 1000);
});
```

Comment: You're calling `set_counter` immediately (`set_counter()`), and passing the result (`undefined`) to `$interval`. `$interval` expects a reference to a function, you need to just pass a reference to `set_counter` to `$interval` - `$interval(set_counter, 1000);`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in on that line

```
$interval(set_counter(), 1000);
```

you are calling the "set_counter" right away not passing it to "$interval" as a callback.

**Fix:**

```
$interval(set_counter, 1000);
```

Comment: And how is that different from the comment provided that worked out the problem?

Comment: You could have upvoted the comment instead of answering here. As @AayushiJain mentioned, its not different from what has been commented.

Comment: you are right I just didn't notice the comment that you are talking about
I thought no one answered at all that's it
and It won't harm answering a question with different words
Thanks anyway

Comment: The comment should have been an answer. Duh.