# $interval not working for callback function, angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, callback

I am a beginner of angularjs, sorry if i asked silly question.

```
function getCams(callback){
  var media_list = [];
  MediaStreamTrack.getSources(function(sourceInfos){
    var i=0;
    while(i!=sourceInfos.length){
      if (sourceInfos[i].kind == 'video'){
        var temp = [];
        temp.push(sourceInfos[i].id);
        temp.push(sourceInfos[i].label);
        media_list.push(temp);
      }
      i++;
    }
    callback(media_list);
  });
}
var app = angular.module('myApp', []).config(function($interpolateProvider){
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');
});
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {
  $scope.cams = [];
  var checkcams = getCams(function(media_list){
    $scope.cams=media_list;
    $scope.$apply();
    console.log("test");
  });
  $interval(checkcams, 10000);
});
```

Above is the code from where i am trying to get the number of cams connected to a system, and trying to update the same in angular js using callback function, In this line

```
$interval(checkcams, 10000);
```

I am trying to call that function after every 10 secs but this function run only once after the page load, and not running after every 10 secs.

I already have a look at this question, it wont help me out.
[$interval not running, angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285535/interval-not-running-angularjs)

Comment: `getCams` is not returning anything, the `$interval` is not working. This is expected behavior.

Comment: So, how to rewrite this code in proper way to update the angular js scope perfectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getCams` is returning nothing hence `$interval` is not working. This is expected behavior.

You can rewrite your code as

```
//Wrap getCams call in a function
var checkcams = function(){
    getCams(function(media_list){
        $scope.cams=media_list;
        $scope.$apply();
        console.log("test");
    });
}

//Call it when view is launched
checkcams();

//set Interval
$interval(checkcams, 10000);
```

Comment: So, only one line is different in this code, what exactly this line is doing here? checkcams();   I want to know the concept behind.

Comment: @SheeshMohsin, Only one line is not different, I have wrapped `getCams` function call in a function and then passed the refrence of that function to interval. read my inline comments

Comment: Yeah, Got it, let me try

Answer (score 0):

By doing this

```
var checkcams = getCams(function(media_list){
$scope.cams=media_list;
$scope.$apply();
console.log("test");
```

});

You have set checkcams to be a variable of whatever getCams returns, not a function.

Try this instead

```
function checkcams () {
    getCams(function(media_list){
        $scope.cams=media_list;
        $scope.$apply();
        console.log("test");
    });
}
$interval(checkcams, 10000);
```